# How to add number Permissions to one role in dnn?

Tags: permissions, roles, dotnetnuke-7

I want add a Permission to one role in DotNetNuke that it can add new page and edit content of pages only. Is this possible?
 Please help

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do this using Oliver Hine's free Enhanced Permissions Provider module:  http://www.oliverhine.com/DotNetNuke/Providers/CustomPermissionsProvider.aspx